# Blank CD less space than there actually is (mac)

Tags: macbook, burning, livecd, compact-disc

I just bought a TDK HC-R90 Recordable blank CD that's supposedly 800 MB, but when I put it in my Macbook, Finder says there's only 100 MB available.  WTF?

I'm trying to burn the 575.8 MB Anonym.OS live cd (.iso), I dunno if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Frost Shadow - just one CD in particular produces this behaviour or the whole series ?

Comment: This is the only one i've tried, and the only one I have.  You think it's a manufacturing error?  I dunno why it would say only 100 MB is available rather than all or nothing, but I don't really know that much about CD manufacturing-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's the deal, apparently since it's an 800 MB disc it's meant for "overburning", where it writes to the very edge of the disc.  However, I guess having the extra room confuses Finder, and after 700 MB, the size of a normal CD, it's starts over, which is why it says my 800 MB disc is only 100 MB.  So... looks like i'll need a 3rd party program that can overburn.  I don't think I actually need to overburn it, since the file I want to write is under 600 MB, and would fit on a normal disc, I just need a program that won't get confused by the larger disc size.

So, I tried firestarter beta; it spit out my disc at around 17% burned, but now when I put the burned disc in and "get info", it says it has 575.8 MB on it.  I dunno how CD writing works, but I guess i'll try to boot from it once I back up everything, since it's probably incomplete and will end up doing something terrible to my HD..

Anyway, just so you know, if anyone was having issues with "High Capacity Recordable" CDs for 90 min / 800 MB.